# JavaScript error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: html

It's giving me an error on line 51

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Validation</title>
</head>

<body>
 
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;padding-right:auto;padding-left:auto;">
<form action="#" method="get" onsubmit="return FormValidation();">

 
 
 <label>Current Password</label>
 <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" maxlength="16" required><br>
 
 
 <label name="notif"></label>
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function FormValidation(){
  var passw = "against";
  var opass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
 
  
  if(opass != passw) {
   document.getElementById("notif").innerHTML = "Your password doesn't match.";
   alert('pass now match');
   return false;
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById("notif").innerHTML = opass + " " + npass + " " + rpass;
  }


 }

</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion why is there an error? I just want to happen is to define the password if correct and notify it on the label.

```
document.getElementById("notif").innerHTML = "Your password doesn't match.";
```

This form for my site forgot password. We with my group is developing a website with a user account and its for a lending cooperative.

Comment: on a side note: everybody who knows how to show the source code of your html/javascript in a browser can read the password - so practically everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to change this line:

```
<label name="notif"></label>
```

to this:

```
<label id="notif"></label>
```

If the name attribute must be retained, you can try jQuery:

```
$("label[name='notif']").html('Your message');
```

Comment: thanks for the tip bro. I'm not yet into jQuery, thanks for the help too ^^

Comment: No prob - glad I could help

Comment: @Student: jQuery can definitely be useful.  Though loading and using that entire library *just* to avoid using an `id` is a bit much.  You can likely get the same functionality from native code using `document.querySelector()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't find anything:

```
document.getElementById("notif")
```

Because there is no element with that `id`.  Thus, this returns nothing and you can't access a property on an undefined object.

Probably the simplest immediate approach would be to give your target element the `id` value you're looking for.  I assume you mean this element:

```
<label name="notif" id="notif"></label>
```

In fact, that `label` *probably* doesn't need the `name` attribute at all.  But that's up to you I guess.

**Edit:** Or, if you want to avoid modifying the markup, you can [use `document.querySelector` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
document.querySelector('input[name="notif"]').innerHTML
```